# Aginity workbench Auto indent / SQL formatter

Tags: workbench, aginity

I am wondering if there is a good SQL formatter in Aginity Workbench 7.2

There is two options which are capitalize keywords and add new line after a semicolon.

Is there an auto-indentation feature?